# Can't change z-index with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index

I, for some reason, can't change the zIndex of an element using jQuery. I've searched all of this website and Google but couldn't find the right answer.
  I am trying to put my element in front of another div when clicking a button. I used the code you can see under here. But didn't work.

```
  $(this).parent().css('zIndex',3000);
```

CSS code of elements it's under in the begin:

```
#wall{
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    position: absolute;
    top:500px;
    background: #11c1e7;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 900;
    }
```

CSS code of element that should go above this:

```
.port1 {
width:200px;
height:200px;
left:<?php echo rand(1,1000); ?>px;
top:-500px;
border-radius: 500px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

// Edit

Link to the site:
http://dannypostma.com/project/j.php

When clicking the portfolio ball, two balls drop from the air. These should go in front of the water when clicked.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and how about some HTML to go with that?

Comment: Thanks! I've added the URL to the page which contains the error.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Setting the `style.zIndex` property has *no effect* on non-positioned elements, that is, the element must be either absolutely positioned, relatively positioned, or fixed.

So I would try:

```
$(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
$(this).parent().css('z-index', 3000);
```

Comment: Indeed... Does the problem occur on all browsers, or just one?

Comment: Both Safari and Chrome have the same problem.

Comment: Your trick works indeed! Made a way around the problem and just changed the water it's z-index. Thanks alot!

Comment: Just as a note to anyone as stupid as myself; I was writing in the wrong line (selector) and setting `z-index` to the body rather than the element I wanted. I should have clicked when I saw the body keep showing a 2147483647 `z-index`. Oh well.

Comment: As of 2017 this was the correct reasoning for why I was having difficulty in Chrome.  Added `relative` position and it worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

That's invalid Javascript syntax; a property name cannot have a `-`.

Use either `zIndex` or `"z-index"`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(this).parent().css('z-index',3000);
```

Comment: The difference between `zIndex`and `z-index` has nothing to do with the issue, at least with a recent version of jQuery

Comment: Are you sure about your selector Danny, try $('#wall').css('z-index',3000)

Comment: For some reason, even that doesn't work. It's like jQuery is completely ignoring this line

Comment: I actually didn't want to target the #wall css, but I can do this aswel. Works like a charm now using Luc1245 trick, thanks for reminding of that!

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, so it's z-index

Comment: @Phillip thanks for warning, i was trying to say you need to add dash :)

Answer (score 0):

because your jQuery code is wrong. 
Correctly would be:

```
var theParent = $(this).parent().get(0); 
$(theParent).css('z-index', 3000);
```

Comment: This for some reason doesn't work either. Nothing is changing.

Comment: Try checking theParent variable, if it is the HTML node object you are looking for. Also you might consider jsbin.com or some other service to show us exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`zIndex` is part of javaScript notation.(camelCase)
but jQuery.css uses same as CSS syntax. 
so it is `z-index`.

you forgot .css("attr","value"). use ' or " in both, attr and val. so, 
`.css("z-index","3000");`

Comment: well, I read it somewhere. 
though,
`$("body").css("borderRight","thin solid black");` and
`$("body").css("border-right","thin solid red");` both works
so I think `zIndex` and `z-index` should too.

Comment: combine above comment with last line in answer and voila!

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem for me. I added the site where the problem occurs. Hope that may help.

Comment: port1 has parent= port? what div should i click? and what div should have got changed?

Comment: Clicking the portfolio ball drops 2 balls. When you hover these, two balls appear. When clicking the right one, the ball sinks and becomes bigger. The problem I have is in the same part of the code. Though it should select the parent correctly because it sinks the ball too.

Answer (score -1):

z-index must be Integer. So try to use parseInt():
$element.css({"z-index", parseInt(z)});

Comment: OP actually wrote a literal integer. It should be ok I guess.