# Property not being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm setting the z-index of a css property using this code :

```
$( ".myIcon").attr("z-index" , 1);
```

But the property is not updating correctly. When I inspect the attribute using Chrome developer tools the z-index remains the same. Is there something I need to fire after using .attr so that the property is updated by the browser ?

Comment: You must add position to it.

Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201855/cant-change-z-index-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) is a style property, you need to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set it

```
$( ".myIcon").css("z-index" , 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.attr()` looks at the **attributes** of the element being targetted. `z-index` is a property of the **style** attribute, **not** an attribute in it's own right. In order to change the `z-index`, you must edit the style attribute on the element using `.css()`

Example:

`$(".myIcon").css("z-index" , 1);`

giving in the html:

`<div class="myIcon" style="z-index: 1">`