# Why does the z-index value remain unchanged, after being changed with the .css() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

The default value for `z-index` is `auto` as based on MDN's documentation.

When I tried setting the `z-index` now to `1` like this:

```
$("body").css("z-index", 1);
```

And the retrieved the `z-index` property like this:

```
$("body").css("z-index");
```

it still returns `auto`.

Why is this happening and how can I retrieve the currently set `z-index` value?

Comment: Try this maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125453/modifying-css-class-property-values-on-the-fly-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: I think your problem is related to the issue in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201855/cant-change-z-index-with-jquery). Basically, unless the element has an absolute, relative or fixed position you can't set the z-index. Not sure if you can make the body element positioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `z-Index` doesn't work with `position:static` elements.

It only works with `position:relative/absolute/fixed` elements.

This might work:

```
elementSelector
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Reference: [z-index - CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: Ok this works! http://jsfiddle.net/HqhBV/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the position of the element then only z-index will work effectively...

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUJY6/1/)

```
<div id="hello">deepak sharma</div>
<input type="button" id="set10" value="set zindex = 10" />
<input type="button" id="set20" value="set zindex = 20" />
<input type="button" id="get" value="get" />
```

---

```
$(function(){
    $("#set10").click(function(){
        $("#hello").css({"z-index":"10","position":"relative"});        
    });
    $("#set20").click(function(){
        $("#hello").css({"z-index":"20","position":"relative"});
    });
    $("#get").click(function(){
        alert($("#hello").css("z-index"));
    });
});
```

---

or you can set the `position:relative` in CSS also then there is no need to set the position in your jquery code.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUJY6/)